# What's the term for the part of the URL after the question mark?

Tags: url, language-agnostic, terminology

`http://www.example.com?foo`

What's the term for the `foo` part of the URL?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

It's the **query**, or sometimes the **query string**.

To pinch a useful diagram from [the URI RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3):

```
     foo://example.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret#nose
     \_/   \______________/\_________/ \_________/ \__/
      |           |            |            |        |
   scheme     authority       path        query   fragment
```

Comment: In the link mentioned in the question, 'http://www.example.com?foo' is it possible to have just foo and no assignment (like 'name=ferret' in your example)? If yes, that what would be foo's work over there?

Comment: @SankalpKotewar No, you cannot have that without a assignment. The query should have the form `field=value`. Check this[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string]

Comment: @SankalpKotewar the convention is to have your query in this format: `?foo=bar&baz=qux` but nothing forces you to do that and the query can pretty much be any text (except it can't contain a `#`). So yes, it's possible. [http://example.com/?????](http://example.com/?????) is a valid URL for example.

Answer (score 6):

It's called the "query string", as you can see [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#Structure).

Answer (score 5):

The query.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the technology you use.
Usually its called *name value* pair. Query string refers to the whole string after ? sign.  Then depending on technology used that query string is parsed and normally appears as the dictionary.
For example, http://www.example.com?foo=bar&foo1=bar1:
Request["foo"] yields "bar"
Request["foo1"] yields "bar1" for asp
or $_GET["foo"] -> "bar" for php and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Here foo is query string,it is a part of the URL, and are therefore included if the user saves or sends the URL to another user.suppose you want to send some input data from url then we use this types of parameater.There are no limit of passing parameters according to RFC 2616.
Syntax of Query String
Request.QueryString(variable)[(index).count]

Answer (score 0):

The 'foo' only is called String Parameters of the URL Query