# What are the strings in website URLs and how do I get them?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the term for the part of the URL after the question mark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007754/whats-the-term-for-the-part-of-the-url-after-the-question-mark)

This question may sound very remedial, but every answer brings me just a little bit more knowledge, and this is a question I had early on but I haven't asked it until now.  I have a company Website in Visual Studio / VB / ASP.NET 4.0.  I noticed a competitor of ours also has .aspx extensions in their website.  They have strings at the end of their website URL.  For instance, when you click a language, it has this after the dot com:

```
/main.aspx?langtype=2057&locale=en-be
```

And of course it goes to that language/culture and the "be" is, I assume, the uiculture/subculture.  But how do you get these strings in your own URL?  I just think it looks professional and advanced.  Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are called QueryStrings and you can use them to pass parameters to another web page.

Here are a couple of links:

This one is CSharp but has good description along the way:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/querystring

Here is something in vb

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5876/Passing-variables-between-pages-using-QueryString

Comment: Thank you for the info and links, D.  I've already skimmed through 'em and bookmarked 'em.  I appreciate you taking the time to respond!

Comment: And I'm assuming that, in the example I showed, that company has a langtype in their database, as much of this seems database-driven, although I could be wrong.  Thanks again!

Comment: Its a pretty good bet that they use it for localization.

Comment: Well, I just got through the process of localizing my entire company's website.  But when I change a language -- and I made it so it lasts the entire session -- it doesn't change the URL.  I don't know if this was good or bad on my part, or if it hurts SEO duplicate content, or what not.

Comment: I have 9 different languages, and clicking on the flag will put the entire website in that language -- but it has no querystrings.  So whatever.com/whatever.aspx just stays like that, although the content switches languages.

Comment: Probably depends on the site itself.  I have no idea what it would do to SEO

Answer (score 3):

That's just one way to pass values between pages. The structure is: main.aspx?variable=value.

Code in Visual Basic:

```
Dim vbvariable = Request.Querystring("variable");
```

then *vbvariable* will be *value*

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yep -- I'm using VB, so I appreciate your response, Aleafonso.  Thank you!

Comment: Actually, the syntax is "page.aspx?Variable1=Value1&Variable2=Value2".  Just using another "/" won't work properly.

Comment: Also, it's always best to declare your variable types "Dim vbvariable as String = Reques.....".

Comment: Thank you for that edit, Bradley.

Comment: Thanks for making it clear @BradleyUffner