# Rewriting Rows instead of adding to new one

Tags: python, excel, web-scraping, data-science, data-analysis

Hello Everyone I am doing a web scraping of a website which has multiple pages(doing for 9 pages) and writing data in a csv file. every page has 24 rows of data which comes in total of 216 rows data for 9 pages but I am getting only 24 rows of data which I think is page no 9 data and python just re-writing the data again & again for every page in same rows instead of appending it.so please help me to figure out how I can make python to append each page data in ex. Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from csv import writer
for page in range(1,10):
    url = 'https://www.flipkart.com/searchq=laptops&otracker=search&otracker1=search&marketplace=FLIPKART&as-show=on&as=off&page={page}'.format(page =page)
    req = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
    links = soup.find_all('div', class_= '_2kHMtA')
    with open('Flipkart.csv', 'w', encoding = 'utf8', newline= '') as f:
        thewriter = writer(f)
        header = ('Title', 'Specification', 'price', 'Rating Out of 5')
        thewriter.writerow(header)
        for link in links:
            title = link.find('div', class_= '_4rR01T').text
            Specification = link.find('ul', class_='_1xgFaf').text
            price = link.find('div', class_ = '_30jeq3 _1_WHN1').text
            Rating = link.find('span', class_='_1lRcqv')
            if Rating:
                Rating = Rating.text
            else:
                Rating = 'N/A'
            info = [title, Specification, price,Rating]
            thewriter.writerow(info)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your `url` is missing a [question mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007754/whats-the-term-for-the-part-of-the-url-after-the-question-mark) after `search`:

```
url = 'https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=laptops&otracker=search&otracker1=search&marketplace=FLIPKART&as-show=on&as=off&page={page}'.format(page =page)
```

Next, change:

```
with open('Flipkart.csv', 'w', encoding = 'utf8', newline= '') as f:
```

into:

```
with open('Flipkart.csv', 'a', encoding = 'utf8', newline= '') as f:
```

as we want to use the mode `a` to *append* to the file. With `w` for *write*, you keep overwriting the file, which is the reason why you end up with only the information from the last page. See [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).

Finally, put the `header` info inside an `if-statement`:

```
        if page == 1:
            header = ('Title', 'Specification', 'price', 'Rating Out of 5')
            thewriter.writerow(header)
```

Otherwise, you will be repeating the header for each new page.

Comment: Thank You so much for clearing out my mistakes with explanation